# Combobox get selected box item?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Here is my ComboBox and I want to check if the comboboxItem with the `name="tweepersonen"` gets selected to do something (WPF)

```
<ComboBox Name="AantalPersonenCombobox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" SelectionChanged="DropdownMenuNachten_SelectionChanged">
     <ComboBoxItem x:Name="tweePersonen" Content="2 Personen"/>
     <ComboBoxItem x:Name="driePersonen" Content="3 Personen"/>
     <ComboBoxItem x:Name="vierPersonen" Content="4 Personen"/>
</ComboBox>
```

c# Code:

```
private void AantalNachtenCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      if(AantalNachtenCombobox.SelectionBoxItem == tweePersonen)
      {
           MessageBox.Show("Your Cheap");                   
      }               
 }
```

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Comment: `== "tweePersonen"`

Answer (score 0):

The way you can access the `ComboBoxItem` to check if the `Name` matches, is by using the `ItemContainerGenerator` of the `ComboBox`:

```cs
private void DropdownMenuNachten_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItemContainer = AantalPersonenCombobox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AantalPersonenCombobox.SelectedIndex) as ComboBoxItem;

    if (selectedItemContainer?.Name == "tweePersonen")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Cheap");
    }
}
```

However, if you don't expect the `ComboBoxItem` content to change then it would be better to check for the content itself: `AantalPersonenCombobox.SelectedItem == "2 Personen"`